# Redirect tag in struts2 jsp page

Tags: java, struts2

I have a jsp page in struts like this:

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<s:if test="#session.variablename == null" >
    **<s:action name="loginForm" />**
</s:if>

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1> 
    <s:a href="doctorLogout">Logout</s:a> 
 <s:include value="/WEB-INF/doctor/doctorFooter.jsp" ></s:include>
```

If `session` is not set, I need to redirect this page to an action in the `struts.xml` page. I have tried the `<jsp:forward />` tag instead of `<s:action />`, but the jsp redirects to the error page. Does this have any solution? Does any redirect tag exist in struts2?

Comment: I would suggest you to use an interceptor that checks if a request has a session attribute set into it for a given action, and if it has session then you redirect the user somewhere (from the interceptor). This way you don't have to duplicate the <s:if tag in every jsp page that requires to verify a session attribute.

Comment: here is a detailed tutorial how to create such interceptor http://www.vitarara.org/cms/struts_2_cookbook/creating_a_login_interceptor and yes don't mix up such logic with presentation

Comment: What you need is a login interceptor. Here is an example.

http://www.onlinexamples.com/showfullexample.action?idexamples=7&title=Login%20Interceptor%20Example

Answer (score 3):

IMO this kind of work belongs in an interceptor, or at worst, a base action class. This kind of logic in a JSP makes testing more difficult.

Struts 2 does not have a redirect tag; use JSTL's `<c:redirect>` tag if you're going to put that kind of logic in a JSP.